# Filter log fle by database name including traceback messages

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I'm trying to filter the log file by database name but when i use grep command i lose the Traceback message

tail -f log.txt

```
2021-05-18 19:05:21,866 1066171 ERROR database1 (...)
Traceback (most recent call last):(...)
  File(...)
2021-05-18 19:05:21,879 1066171 INFO database1 (...)
2021-05-18 19:05:21,866 1066171 ERROR database2 (...)
Traceback (most recent call last):(...)
  File(...)
```

tail -f log.txt | grep database1

```
2021-05-18 19:05:21,866 1066171 ERROR database1 (...)
2021-05-18 19:05:21,879 1066171 INFO database1 (...)
```

How can i filter all messeges from database1 including Treceback lines

Comment: If you are looking for a specific traceback, you can use grep's `-A` to always list a specific number of lines after the matching line. Otherwise you will need to use a tool more powerful than grep to do multiline lexing. Some common options are logstash, fluentd, or an ugly perl script.

Answer (score 0):

If traceback is always after error line then this should do:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep -A1 database1 | grep -E "database1|Traceback"
```